# Does the following hold $(z^2)^\frac{1}{2}=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is the following true $(z^2)^\frac{1}{2}=z$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Why is this question on the way to being "closed"?  Generated some nice answers and discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true even for reals $((-2)^2)^{1/2}\ne -2$. In fact for every complex nonzero $p$ the expression  $p^{1/2}$ is not a number but a set consisting of two numbers.

Comment: For $z\ne0$, $z\in \{ (z^2)^{1/2} \}$.

Comment: $\in$ is different from $=$.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you.  Maybe my comment is superfluous.  By the way, thinking that $0$ is not included because it is a branch point.

Comment: The issue here is not just a branch point but the monodromy group which does not let you choose a canonical square root.

Comment: The issue is what you mean by $(z^2)^{1/2}$.  There are basically two ways to interpret this: either the $1/2$ power is a multivalued function or you choose a particular branch.  In the first case, $(z^2)^{1/2}$ is a set of two complex numbers, one of which is $z$ and the other $-z$.  In the second case, assuming $z \ne 0$ the equation will be true for one of $z$ and $-z$ and false for the other.

Comment: That is what I was trying to explain. Because of the monodromy group there is no way one can choose a branch. You can do it for  real numbers because there is no path from $a$ to $-a$ avoiding $0$, but you cannot do it in $\Bbb C$ because you can move continuously from $z$ to $-z$ avoiding $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not for any $z$. The rules in the complex field are extended from real numbers.